# efficient join needed against a virtual table used multiple times in a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, join, average

I am trying to run a query similar to this one:

```
SELECT s.custno, 
       s.prodno, 
       IF(daycode = 1, (SELECT avg(sell) 
                        FROM   sales ss 
                               JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT `prodno` 
                                     FROM   `familycode` 
                                     WHERE  prodfamily = 101) f2 
                                 ON f2.prodno = ss.prodno 
                        WHERE  ss.CUSTNO = 800 
                               AND ss.weekno = s.weekno - 1), (SELECT avg(sell) 
                                                               FROM   sales ss 
                                                                      JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT `prodno`
                                                                            FROM   `familycode`
                                                                            WHERE  prodfam = 101) f3
                                                                        ON f3.prodno = ss.prodno
                                                               WHERE  ss.CUSTNO = 800 
                                                                      AND ss.weekno = s.weekno)) AS weekavg
FROM   sales s 
       JOIN product p 
         ON p.prodno = s.prodno 
       JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT `prodno` 
             FROM   `familycode` 
             WHERE  prodfamily = 101) f 
         ON f.prodno = s.prodno 
WHERE  s.CUSTNO = 800 
ORDER  BY ardate8n ASC, 
          s.CUSTNO, 
          s.prodno
```

In this query I would like the get the products week average based on the daycode param for a product family.

A product belongs to a product family.

- If daycode = 1 I want to get for the same product family the average of the previous week.
- else I want to get average on the current week for the same product family.

As you see `f`,`f2`,`f3` are similar virtual tables, that helps us to link against existing products based on product family.

How could this query be rewritten so to not compute `f2`, `f3` tables, which is a very slow process.

Comment: I think you need to rewrite your question to clearly state your goals, what data you have to work with, and any constrains you are dealing with. From your responses to me, it appears as though your columns are poorly named, thus making it a hit or miss.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a mysql environment available to me atm, this is from memory and not run against some mocked up tables.

first, i would try to stick to just joins, as the only filtering done against familycode is a 'distinct' marker. I do not know the data in familycode, so compare a working slow query to the new one and watch for a 'sales spike' from duplicates!

```
FROM   sales ss 
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT `prodno` 
FROM   `familycode` 
 WHERE  prodfamily = 101) f2 
ON f2.prodno = ss.prodno 
WHERE  ss.CUSTNO = 800
```

becomes

```
 FROM   sales ss 
JOIN familycode f2 
ON f2.prodno = ss.prodno 
WHERE  ss.CUSTNO = 800 and f2.prodfamily = 101
```

My second approach, and if you get duplicates sales spike issue, would be to try an 'exists' clause instead of a 'distinct' clause.  that solution would look like this:

```
FROM   sales ss 
    JOIN familycode f2 
    ON f2.prodno = ss.prodno 
    WHERE  ss.CUSTNO = 800 and exists (select 1 from familycode f2 where f2.prodno = ss.prodno and f2.prodfamily= 101)
```

Comment: `Exists` clause is usually mutch slower than `joins`. Indeed I get duplicates on the sales table if I use this way.

Comment: @Pentium10 sure.  I would use Kevin's idea of creating a view, but of just 'f2' and join on that.  test the times, as the mysql sql compiler May be doing that already for f1,f2,f3 in the execution plan.  The view would help keep 'f2' in Cache at that point. if it's still needs tweaking, then I would go all the way down kevin's route of a complex view.  I prefer views simple, as reports Always get changed.

Comment: I can agree with your assessment. I was just trying to solve the ops entire problem. One could easily create a view for f2 and one to report like this using the f2 view. That way the report would be a bit easier to alter in the future. And the caching of f2 wouldn't be lost for other reports.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm a bit confused, but here's my go at it. It would have been helpful if you showed some sample output with your question. I also don't see any correlation with `ardate8n` nor do I completely understand how `ss.weekno = s.weekno - 1` works for you. I hope this helps somehow. If it isn't working towards your goals please expand you answer to include expected output, table definitions, and what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Basically it sounds like you have a `sales`, `product`, and `productfamily` table and need to report on the average sales of all products in a product family during a given week (whether it is the current week or the previous one). If I understand this correctly, the following SELECT should work out and be pretty fast, however it will get you all products and every week.

```
SELECT p.prodno, f.familycode, s.custno, s.weekno, AVG( s.sell ) as sales_avg
    FROM sale s
    JOIN product p USING(prodno)
    JOIN productfamily f USING(prodno)
GROUP BY s.weekno, f.familycode, p.prodno
ORDER BY s.weekno
```

Now, turn this into a view.

```
CREATE VIEW "main"."view_weekly_product_sales_avg" AS 
SELECT p.prodno, f.familycode, s.custno, s.weekno, AVG( s.sell ) as sales_avg
    FROM sale s
    JOIN prod p USING(prodno)
    JOIN prodfamily f USING(prodno)
GROUP BY s.weekno, f.familycode, p.prodno
ORDER BY s.weekno;
```

Then query the view/report how you need. From your example, I think you would query it like this:

```
SELECT prodno, custno, sales_avg
    FROM view_weekly_product_sales_avg
WHERE familycode = 1 AND custno = 1 AND weekno = 1
```

For me this reports out the following table:

```
prodno  custno  sales_avg
1       1       37.3333333333333
2       1       12.0
3       1       78.0
8       1       12.0
```

Comment: Your assumptions are almost correct. That weekno is there for the following: For products listed on monday I need to get the average of the previous week, for the rest of the days I need to get the average against current week. Each average should be based on the the average of product family on that week, and not global sales average for that week. You group by's doesn't help me, because I need to get each product on each date, so they should not be grouped at all. Ardate8n is the date the sale happen.

Comment: Please note also the any `group by weekno` is incorrect in MySQL, the recommended way is `yearweek(ardate8n)`, this won't break week numbers across year end/start too.

Comment: I don't need any average performed on the outer select. I need the previous week average selected next to each product. This is computed in the subquery.